# XSLT - Generating HTML from XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

In XSL I need to generate HTML tags depending on what iteration of the for-each i am..

For example, if I have the following XML:

```
<Items>
  <Car>Mercedes</Car>
  <Bike>Gt</Bike>
  <House>123</House>
  <Skate>111</Skate>
  <Plane>5522</Plane>
  <tv>Sony</tv>
</Items>
```

And with my XSL y need to generate the HTML displaying 2 items for each row.
I need to display only 4 tds per row, 2 of them with the title and the 2 others with the value.
With my previous example the expected HTML would be:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Car</td>
  <td>Mercedes</td>
  <td>Bike</td>
  <td>Gt</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>House</td>
  <td>123</td>
  <td>Skate</td>
  <td>111</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Plane</td>
  <td>5522</td>
  <td>tv</td>
  <td>Sony</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I,ve tried with when/otherwise inside the for-each, opening or closing the `<tr>`, but the XSL is invalid..

Is there a way to achieve this??

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Items">
    <table>
      <xsl:for-each select="*[position() mod 2 != 0]">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="name(following-sibling::*)"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Car</td>
    <td>Mercedes</td>
    <td>Bike</td>
    <td>Gt</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>House</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>Skate</td>
    <td>111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Plane</td>
    <td>5522</td>
    <td>tv</td>
    <td>Sony</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```